# Swift: export API of dependency

Tags: swift, cocoapods

Suppose we have 2 frameworks written in Swift: `A.framework` and `B.framework`, `A` depends on `B`. I want every project depending on `A` to be able to access api of framework `B` without having to `import B` in project source files. How it can be achieved?

**EDIT**: Particularly I'm intrested how this can be done via Cocoapods.

**ANOTHER EDIT**: I think it will be helpful if I explain context in which this question arise, because I still didn't get suitable answer despite of it's duration and bounty.

So, I have pod `Freestyler` (https://github.com/cayugasoft/Freestyler) which itself depends on pod `FreestylerCore` (https://github.com/cayugasoft/FreestylerCore). Works fine, but I have to `import FreestylerCore` in project even if `import Freestyler` is done. It looks a little bit annoying for me, because I consider this dependency (`Freestyler -> FreestylerCore`) as implementation detail and I would like if users of library automatically have this things working without importing anything else except the main pod, `Freestyler`. So, that's why I asked this question. Are there any ways to implement this?

Comment: correct me if wrong, since A depends on B and has import B in source files of A. Now you would like to have a project P without having to do import B in P source files ? Is that right ? If that's the case you ultimately want to add B as a dependency for A  and add only A as a dependency of P ?

Comment: @PenkeySuresh: I basically want something like umbrella header in Objective-C. You import this header and all other headers are imported automatically and you don't have to import them manually. I'm wondering if there is mechanism to implement similar behavior, but in Swift.

Comment: I think what you're looking for is `@_exported`.

Comment: @HAS: Yes, it works! Please make an answer and I'll accept it. I decided not to use it in project I mention above, because: 1. it's kind of private, undocumented attribute which may be removed at any time; 2. looks like it doesn't work for custom operators (I always get error **Operator is not a known binary operator**). But in any case, it's good to know such thing exists.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that in Swift, this is the default behavior.

If Pod.A depends on Pod.B, then your project that depends on Pod.A (via inclusion of Pod.A in your Podfile) will indeed have visibility to Pod.B.

To see an example of how to setup a Pod.A that has a dependency, and then an Example project that consumes Pod.A (and also has visibility to Pod.B) see my Public GitHub Repo Demo for this:

https://github.com/ericwastaken/CocoaPod-Dependency-Demo

I added comments to Example App (ViewController) that shows this working. The repo has additional explanations.

Comment: Thank you for answer, @ericWasTaken. Unfortunately, it's not what I meant. It's clear that you can use pod B in project that depends on pod A, *if you import pod B*, but I asked how to achieve this *without importing pod B, only importing pod A*. I looked at your github example - if line `import StackO_Dependency_Demo` in ViewController is commented out, code will not compile.

Comment: My example app never references Pod.B in the Podfile. Pod.B is the React pod! My example only references Pod.A and that automatically gives you access to Pod.B (the react pod) which comes via Pod.A (the StackO pod = Pod.A). Of course if you remove Pod.A it won't build. That's the main Pod used in the view controller. In any case, perhaps you're looking for a static inclusion of the Pod.B logic. You can of course bring those classes into your Pod.A and compile together as a single Pod. But that's not how CocoaPod ultimately works nor what it is for.

Comment: Yes looking at your question now, if you don't want the import statements at all, then you need to include the Pod.B logic code/classes in your Pod.A. Perhaps you can fork Pod.B and then add your own logic to it. At least this way you might be able to merge changes into your fork in the future.